# How to get the key and value of ArrayList in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a array list which contain the objects with key value pair,but unable to get the key and value,here how the debugger look like:

[image]

Comment: What is the type of the object inside ArrayList? KeyValuePair? 
Have you tried to convert it manually? Like this: var keyValue =  list[1] as KeyValuePair.

Comment: And I recommend you to use Dictionary for this things of course.

Comment: I get the array list from dll file,the function already secretly cast inside the dll and return in array list.

Answer (score 1):

The `ArrayList`  designed for heterogeneous collections of objects, when accessing an explict cast is required to underlying data type.

Use simple `foreach` and you could read `<key, value>` like this.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in arrayList)
{
    ...
}
```